# A/B testing-question on ad placement

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

I need help on building the thought process to get to the answer to the following question:

"You want to test which of the two ad placements on your website is better. How many visitors and/or how many times each ad is clicked do we need so that we can be 95% sure that one placement is better?"

I understand it is related to A/B testing, but have no clue how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have counts of clicks for each of
the two placements during a particular period of time.
Then you need to take into consideration the following:

(a) About what proportions of the time do you get clicks on the ad (clicks/visits)? [Proportions near $1/2$ lead to higher variability (thus larger required sample sizes) than do proportions nearer to $0$ or $1.]$

(b) What difference in proportions would you want to be sure to detect? [It will be easier to detect the difference $\Delta = .10$ between $0.70$ and $0.80$ than the difference $\Delta = .01$ between $0.70$ and $0.71.]$

(c) What do you mean by "95% sure"? [Do you want a two-sided test of $H_O: p_1= p_2$ against
$H_1: p_1 \ne p_2$ to be rejected with probability $0.95$ testing at the 5% level of significance when
the true difference is $\Delta$ as in (b)? Thisis called the 'power' of the test.]

There are 'power and sample' size calculators
in various statistical software programs and
also some useful ones online. I know of no simple formula.

Also, you can get good approximations
using simulation. To get you started thinking
about scenarios for your particular situation,
I will show a couple of power approximations
using R and its implementation of `prop.test`.

```
n = 1500 # visits to sites with each ad placement
p.1 = .80;  p.2 = .85 # proportions of clicks
set.seed(2021)
pv = replicate(10^5,prop.test(c(rbinom(1,n,p.1),rbinom(1,n,p.2)),
                     c(n,n))$p.val)
mean(pv <.05)
[1] 0.94504  # approx power
```

The same program with `n=2000` gives approximate
power 0.98 and `n=1000` gives approximate power 0.83.

The first of the 100,000 iterations in the program rejected $H_0$ with P-value near $0,$ based on simulated observed
proportions about $0.802$ and $0.859,$ respectively.

```
set.seed(2021)
x.1 = rbinom(1, 1500, .8); x.1
[1] 1203
x.2 = rbinom(1, 1500, .85); x.2
[1] 1289
prop.test(c(x.1,x.2), c(1500,1500))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    with continuity correction

data:  c(x.1, x.2) out of c(1500, 1500)
X-squared = 17.122, df = 1, p-value = 3.506e-05
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
  -0.08476269 -0.02990398
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.8020000 0.8593333
```

Comment: These code examples run on `R version 4.0.2`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! As I had suspected, it's relatively non-trivial for a beginner like me. How exactly to answer this in an interview? I'm guessing just discussing the process should be enough?

Comment: Yes, for an interview, say sample size depends on how far click rates are from 1/2, how much of a difference you want to detect, significance level, and desired power. Might also mention online 'power and sample size' utilities, most of which deal with equal sample sizes btw the two groups. Usually for two different sample sizes (inefficient choice, but sometimes req'd due to cost) you'd need to use simulation. // FYI, in eh hypothetical scenario of my Answer, sample size for diff btw .80 & .85 is same as for  diff btw .20 and .15.